# How to best maintain a script in a large amount of spreadsheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am about to release an application (time sheet) where up to 80 users will work on their own time sheet which I shared to them. All those sheet currently contain 2 scripts (onOpen and onEdit) which support the user entering his data.

Now my worry is to update all those 80 scripts if I have to do a change in the script at some point in time.

Is there a best practice on how to do that? Can I use the "Publish as a service" function for that? If yes, how do I apply this service in those 80 spreadsheets?

Any thougths are welcome.

Heinz

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy, standard way to do this yet. We all hope it will be much easier when [issue 40](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=40) is solved. You should star it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

Now, there's some of workarounds for this. It's possible that one may suit you. Some of them are described on [issue 40](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=40) comments, you should really read it.

The first one is the "remote code fetching". Where each of your 80 scripts will have just a skeleton script that will fetch the code to be executed remotely. Possibly stored on a cell in the "mother" spreadsheet, or a site, anywhere you can access easily from your script. Here is an example:

```js
var sourceScript = 'url-to-your-script-file-hosted-anywhere';

function onEdit() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(sourceScript).getContentText());
  onEditImpl(); //this function is declared on the imported script
}

function onOpen() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(sourceScript).getContentText());
  onOpenImpl(); //this function is declared on the imported script
}

//only hold the API calls that you may do on the imported script
//so there's a nice authorization popup for the user
function stub() {
  return;
  SpreadsheetApp.openById('').getRange('').setValue('');
  CalendarApp.getCalendarById('').createAllDayEvent('', null);
  SitesApp.getSite(''); //and so on...
  //add/remove all services you'll use here in the stub
  //more is better, in case you decide the script have to something new
  //you don't have to go and edit each script manually :)
}
```

Another possible workaround is to have a "template" spreadsheet, with the script in it. So that you can recreate all your 80 spreadsheets by copying from it again (with the updated script), and the copy the values and permissions for each file onto the new one. The drawback of this approach is that all link to the files will change. Each user settings for the file, comments, folder, etc, will be lost. But again, depending on your usage, on how they access the files, e.g. they may not even have a Google account, it can be shared for anyone with the link, which is in your site. I don't know the scenario, it may suit you.

That's all I can think with the limitation you told (to use onOpen and onEdit). All very clumsy and not real solutions. But for now, that's all we got.

Comment: Hello Henrique,

I do like your idea:

function onEdit() {
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(sourceScript).getContentText());
  onEditImpl(); //this function is declared on the imported script

However, I would imagine this to be quite slow. Wouldn't it? I use onEdit() script to support the User entering data and to control data entry errors, so responses must be pretty fast.

Thanks anyway.

Heinz

Comment: You could "cache" the code somewhere locally, e.g a script property, cache service, hidden cell, etc. and have some other function just to update it (or expire it). Anyway, there will always be an overhead, nothing will ever compare to the code directly there. But IMHO, onEdit is never "pretty fast", it's naturally slow. I guess you have try and see if this difference will really matter in your use-case. But again, this is not a real solution, just a workaround with lots of compromises.

Comment: Is UrlFetchApp available in the context of onOpen\onEdit??? From my experiments and from you answer at http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps-script/MFHOXuSFK_0%5B1-25%5D it seems not. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: UrlFetch is available for onEdit/onOpen, as it is not related to the user. e.g. you can perfectly UrlFetch a google result based on an edit and present it on a popup to the user. What you can't do on simple event handlers is access anything that requires the user credentials. Anyway, [issue 40](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=40) is already solved! So non of this is required/relevant anymore.